# Is it correct to call semget() followed by semop() without calling semctl()?

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore

I was going through the example program for semaphores in [Beej's Guide to Unix IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html#semsamp).

The example program contains the following semaphore initialization code. I am only posting a snippet from it that is relevant to the question. To see the complete code, visit the link I have provided above.

```
/*
** initsem() -- more-than-inspired by W. Richard Stevens' UNIX Network
** Programming 2nd edition, volume 2, lockvsem.c, page 295.
*/
int initsem(key_t key, int nsems)  /* key from ftok() */
{
    int i;
    union semun arg;
    struct semid_ds buf;
    struct sembuf sb;
    int semid;

    semid = semget(key, nsems, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);

    if (semid >= 0) { /* we got it first */
        sb.sem_op = 1; sb.sem_flg = 0;
        arg.val = 1;

        printf("press return\n"); getchar();

        for(sb.sem_num = 0; sb.sem_num < nsems; sb.sem_num++) { 
            /* do a semop() to "free" the semaphores. */
            /* this sets the sem_otime field, as needed below. */
            if (semop(semid, &sb, 1) == -1) {
                int e = errno;
                semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID); /* clean up */
                errno = e;
                return -1; /* error, check errno */
            }
        }
```

Here is what I am unable to understand. Once `semget()` creates semaphores and returns successfully with a valid semaphore ID, the semaphores themselves are uninitialized and in an indeterminate state. This is confirmed by the man page of `semget`.

> **Semaphore initialization**
>
> The values of the semaphores in a newly created set are indeterminate.  (POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008 are explicit on this point, although POSIX.1-2008 notes that a future version of the standard may
>   require an implementation to initialize the semaphores to 0.)  Although Linux, like many other implementations, initializes the semaphore values to 0, a portable application cannot rely  on  this:  it
>   should explicitly initialize the semaphores to the desired values.
>
> Initialization can be done using semctl(2) SETVAL or SETALL operation.  Where multiple peers do not know who will be the first to initialize the set, checking for a nonzero sem_otime in the associated
>   data structure retrieved by a semctl(2) IPC_STAT operation can be used to avoid races.

But in the above code `semctl()` was not called to initialize the semaphores. Instead, `semop()` was called with `sem_op` = `1`, which according to the man page of `semop` does the following.

> If sem_op is a positive integer, the operation adds this value to the semaphore value (semval).  Furthermore, if SEM_UNDO is specified for this operation, the system subtracts the  value  sem_op  from
>   the semaphore adjustment (semadj) value for this semaphore.  This operation can always proceed—it never forces a thread to wait.  The calling process must have alter permission on the semaphore set.

But without initialization, `semval` was indeterminate. So adding `1` to it still leaves it indeterminate.

Is this code incorrect or is my understanding incorrect? If my understanding is incorrect, could you please explain me why this code is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, the code is not portable. The [POSIX.1-2008 specification of `semget`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semget.html) does not require the semaphore to be initialized:

> Upon creation, the **semid_ds** data structure associated with the new
>   semaphore identifier is initialized as follows:
>
> - In the operation permissions structure `sem_perm.cuid`, `sem_perm.uid`,  `sem_perm.cgid`, and `sem_perm.gid` shall be set to the
>     effective user ID and effective group ID, respectively, of the calling
>     process.
> - The low-order 9 bits of `sem_perm.mode` shall be set to the low-order 9 bits of `semflg`.
> - The variable `sem_nsems` shall be set to the value of `nsems`.
> - The variable `sem_otime` shall be set to 0 and `sem_ctime` shall be set to the current time, as described in [IPC General Description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_07_01).
> - The data structure associated with each semaphore in the set **need not be initialized**. The [`semctl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semctl.html) function with the command SETVAL or
>     SETALL can be used to initialize each semaphore.

Comment: It should be noted that "need not be initialized" doesn't mean, the implementation is forbidden to initialize it. So, the posted code might just have worked all time, because it always ran on a system, that initialized the data to 0. But the next system, the code is ported to, might not do it, and then the code crashes or misbehaves in suble ways.

Answer (score 2):

## Disclaimer

This was not supposed to be an answer, but it wouldn't fit in the comments as it kept growing...

---

## The Technical Domain

[**Tim**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164344/tim) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754069/1928852) your question pretty well in the technical domain (*which is what SO is all about*). However, I'm feeling *philosophical* tonight and I think that the source of your doubt may be more subtle: I think that your question is more about *the context and the author* than it is about the code.

---

## A Load of Personal Opinions

From what you posted:

> **Semaphore initialization**
>
> *The values of the semaphores in a newly created set are indeterminate.* (POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008 are explicit on this point, although POSIX.1-2008 notes that a future version of the standard may require an implementation to initialize the semaphores to 0.) **Although Linux, like many other implementations, initializes the semaphore values to 0, a portable application cannot rely on this: it should explicitly initialize the semaphores to the desired values.**

You're following a guide which has the title: "*Beej's Guide to Unix IPC*". Some **very** important things should pop out when you read a title like that:

1. it's a one person view of something - it's **his** way of doing it. Specifically, a person named Brian Hall that goes by the nickname of "Beej".
2. it specifically says it's for Unix (Linux actually, see bellow).
3. if you read [Beej's resume](http://beej.us/brian_beej_hall_resume.pdf)(PDF), you'll see that by the range of domains he has knowledge in, he's no simple programmer. He's a **tinkerer**, and tinkerers do whatever the hell they want. That's why they're the clever dudes - they make lots of mistakes, thus, they learn a whole lot more than others.

Therefore, the author may do anything he wants and he may write whatever he wants in the paper - that includes using platform specific features/bugs/traps/standards/etc. There's a [part in the article](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html#platform) that explicitly tells you the *POSIXey* nature of the article and the platform in which this code is meant to be compiled and run:

> **1.1. Audience**
>
> If you know C or C++ and are pretty good using a Unix environment (**or other POSIXey** environment that supports these system calls) these documents are for you.
>
> (...)
>
> **1.2. Platform and Compiler**
>
> The examples in this document were **compiled under Linux using gcc**. They should compile anywhere a good Unix compiler is available.

Again, more loads of personal opinion: he's saying that he's using **Linux** and **gcc**. So, the title could have been rewritten as:

### Unreliable Hacker's Guide to Linux IPC programming using GCC

That sounds a lot like a [Rusty Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rusty_Russell)'s article title! (Another tinkerer, by the way). Anyway, **with a title like that, would you really be concerned about POSIX?**